# mysql_insert_id always returns 1 , with no rows added in the DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with the following code :

```
    $sql = "insert into " . $mainDb .
    ".carrot_purchases_history(userid,pack_id,type,type_amount,carrots,coins,purchase_date,order_id)
    values(".$userid.",-66,".$type.",".$amount.",0,0,now(),".$order_id.")";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $cph_id = mysql_insert_id();

    if ($cph_id < 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return $cph_id;
```

cph_id is always returned as 1 . The table does have an autoincrement . Also no records are entered in the table. When I run the same query in phpmyadmin it works and enters a record. Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong

**EIDT:** Turns out the issue was with how I was printing the stuff. The query and the rest is working. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: You might want to use more error handling in your PHP to make sure your PHP doesn't screw up. Starting with an `if` for the `mysql_query`. Perhaps a quote or something is misplaced or whatever

Comment: It would help to see your CREATE TABLE query so that we know why you're passing in an `ID` and looking for a `cph_id`.

Comment: @Carl, I've tested the query in a php syntax checker that is fine. Also I have executed the same query in the queryexecutor inside phpmyadmin and it inserted a row properly.

Comment: @FahimAkhter Can you use this ans paste the result here `echo 'LAST_INSERT_ID: ',
          mysql_query( "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" ),
          '<br>mysql_insert_id: ',
          mysql_insert_id();`

Comment: How are type and userid being prepared?

Comment: `mysql_query` returns boolean true if the insert query succeeds and boolean false if it fails. What is the value of `$query` (and what is the error message)?

Comment: The issue was when I was echoing the answer not with the answer itself. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 1):

If your table already have autoincrement for primary key, you can omit `id` from your insert query.
It will be automatically get inserted by `MySQL`

Comment: id is not the primary key, I just changed it to userid in the question for clarification.